# Lazy Load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

I'm trying to create a web page where the images load as i scroll down the page.. 
So i tried the [lazy load plugin](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). At the moment i cant even see my image. A border of where the image should be loads but that's it. I can however see the image if i did src="" instead of data-original=""...

Here's what i have tried:

head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
```

body:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="images/firstImage.jpg" data-placement="auto" width="765" height="574">
```

js (posted all my js incase i have incorrectly placed some of it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
});

$(".burger").click(function() {    //burger button
    $(".site-navigation-menu").toggleClass("show"); 
    $(".banter_ul").toggleClass("show"); 
    $(".bar1, .bar2, .bar3").toggleClass("burgerColor");
    $(".burger").toggleClass("burgerFixed");
});

});

function myFunction(x) {    //burger animation 
x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Just have and it says this: http://localhost:8013/jquery.lazyload.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)